# Matlab number with e

Tags: matlab, numbers, decimal, rounding

I work with matlab.My answer is this

```
1.0e-13 *

-0.4710
0.0133
```

I tried format long g but this time answer is

```
-4.70969527418052e-14
```

I do not want number with e.How can fixed this?

Comment: What do you want to display? `-0.0000000000000470969527418052`?

Comment: So you want the output to be `-0.000000000000047`? Or do you want it as `-4.70969x10^-14`?

Comment: I want to -0.0000000000000470969527418052

Comment: Does that really seem like a good idea? Those decimals are most likely not be precise anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sprintf('%0.55f',your_var)` if you want. Change how many decimals you want printed by changing the number. Its 55 in this example.

I think this is a terrible idea. You are plotting raw floating point representation, it confuses you more than it helps. If you need accuracy in decimals of the order of e-20, you may be doing something wrong, or just not using the right tool.

I think before you continue you should have a read to the following post:

[Why is 24.0000 not equal to 24.0000 in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab)

Comment: I don't need accuracy, I just want to get the long version of number.

Comment: @Sun if you dont care about the decimal values (i.e. you dont need accuracy), then why would you want to print them? I added the disclaimer because of that doubt.

Answer (score 1):

There is another possibility using the symbolic toolbox:

```
precision=64
vpa(sym(z,"f"),64)
```

The output is:

```
-0.00000000000004709999999999999620518877985217527098343349989395534294089884497
```